# If $S$ is a free $R$-algebra, then no element of $S$ is integral over $R$? And other questions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, algebras

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings.

1. If $S$ is any $R$-algebra (not necessarily finitely generated), then every element of $S$ is written as a polynomial with coefficients in $R$ ?
2. If $s \in S$ is integral over $R$, then there exists a monic polynomial over $R$, say $p(x) \in R[x]$, such that $p(s)=0$. So, if $S$ is a free $R$-algebra, then no element of $S$ is integral over $R$?

Comment: Except the elements of $R$, of course, so what you really meant to say is "No element of $S \setminus R$ is integral over $R$", i.e. $R$ is integrally closed in $S$.

Comment: 1. makes not much sense. Do you perhaps fix a generating set $X$ and ask if the map $R[X]\to S$ is surjective? Then the answer is yes.